# how to pass a whole row as record to a function in oracle triggers

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I create a oracle package with function where in the input is a whole row and the output is varray. i want to use this package function to apply on all the rows of a table using trigger as soon as new record is inserted. I tried like this but the output is bad bind variable

```
create or replace trigger custdata_caferrors 
before insert or update on customer_data
referencing new as n old as o
for each row 
declare 
    v_remarks varchar(500)  :=' ';
    t_remarks caf_errors :=caf_errors();
    rec customer_data%rowtype;
begin
--    rec  = :n;
    t_remarks  := CUSTDATA_VERIFY.VERIFY_TERMSTATUS(:n);
    for x in 1..t_remarks.count
        loop
            v_remarks :=v_remarks||' ,  '||t_remarks(x);
       end loop;
     :n.record_status1 :=v_remarks;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to reference a whole new row in a trigger. I agree it would be neat if this were possible, but alas.

So you will have to explicitly populate your `rec` variable with the column values you require and pass that to your function, like this

```
create or replace trigger custdata_caferrors 
before insert or update on customer_data
referencing new as n old as o
for each row 
declare 
    v_remarks varchar(500)  :=' ';
    t_remarks caf_errors :=caf_errors();
    rec customer_data%rowtype;
begin

    rec.id   := :n.id;
    rec.col1 := :n.col1;
    -- etc

    t_remarks  := CUSTDATA_VERIFY.VERIFY_TERMSTATUS(rec);
    for x in 1..t_remarks.count
        loop
            v_remarks :=v_remarks||' ,  '||t_remarks(x);
       end loop;
     :n.record_status1 :=v_remarks;
end;
/
```

Do you really need to pass the whole row to CUSTDATA_VERIFY.VERIFY_TERMSTATUS()? If not you might get away with populating just the columns the function actually uses (although that does contravene the Law of Demeter).